# Replace values in multiple untitled columns to 0, 1, 2 depending on column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

EDITED AS PER COMMENTS

**Background:** Here is what the current dataframe looks like. The row labels are information texts in original excel file. But I hope this small reproduction of data will be enough for a solution? Actual file has about 100 columns and 200 rows.

Column headers and Row #0 values are repeated with pattern shown below -- except the `Sales`  or `Validation` text changes at every occurrence of column with an existing title.

One more column *before* sales with text in each row. Mapping of Xs done for this test. Unfortunately, found no elegant way of displaying text as part of output below.

```
 Sales Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Validation Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6
0       Commented  No comment             Commented  No comment                                   
1     x                                             x                        
2                            x          x                                                
3                x                                             x
```

**Expected Output**: Replacing the X with 0s, 1s and 2s depending on which column they are in (Commented / No Comment)

```
 Sales Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Validation Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6
0       Commented  No comment             Commented  No comment                                   
1     0                                            1                        
2                            2          0                                                
3                1                                             2
```

**Possible Code**: I assume the loop would look something like this:

```
while in row 9:
    if column value = "commented":

        replace all "x" with 1

    elif row 9 when column valkue = "no comment":

        replace all "x" with 2

    else:

        replace all "x" with 0
```

But being a python novice, I am not sure how to convert this to a working code. I'd appreciate all support and help.

Comment: Dear @Erfan, thank you for your comment. I'm new to python, pandas and SO. Don't know how to recreate a mapped DF with Xs (image 1) as copy-pasteable data. I can imagine it to be easier for data with unique text strings and titled columns. Previously I was encouraged to share images of my DF and I used the same approach here. If there is a better way you know, I'd love to learn.

Comment: To ask a good question all is explained in the link provided by @Erfan, basically the idea is to give a sample of your dataframe using head or/and tail or/and sample depending on the structure of the DataFrame (sometimes all rows look the same, sometimes there is some kind of order). Then you can print it out and copy it on stackoverflow so that we can work with it. Also you should print the expected output for the particular DataFrame you gave as input for people to see if they give you good results.

Comment: @SmileyProd. Thank you! Started looking at the links. How do I print the dataframe output in the question? If I just type the code as `df = pd.Dataframe...` will that be enough?

Comment: If in `pd.DataFrame()` you put data that we can copy paste, it would be enough for us to reproduce it, but you should make it appear on stackoverflow as a table to make us see it. The idea is to whether print it like this `print(df.to_string())` and copy paste the output on stack overflow, or if you're running it locally, run `df.to_clipboard()` and paste it on stackoverflow (it automatically copy the df so that you can paste it). Then we can copy it thanks to `pd.read_clipboard()` or if you also gave us `pd.DataFrame(data)` just run your code.

Comment: @SmileyProd, I didn't know it was possible to copy paste outputs to questions asked here. Thank you and for the useful input. Will try and see how I can add this to the question and revise it accordingly.

Comment: You can also use something like `df.to_dict('records')` and just give 10 lines of that (for example), in `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` where `data` is the 10 lines you extracted in your previous step. Essentially, if we can just copy/paste code into an interpreter and have a ready-made df then you have a lot better chance of getting help. It's not that we're lazy, there's just a handful of people trying to address a huge number of questions.

Comment: @SmileyProd is the revision better now?

Comment: @Erfan, is the revision better now?

Comment: Yes it is better, how do you know that a column has a title or has no title ?

Comment: Yes, that's better. Removed downvote and voted for re-open. Question: is the row with `commented` and `no commented` an actual row or multiindex column?

Comment: @SmileyProd, the column with `Title` has a title and changes for each instance.

Comment: @Erfan thank you for your help and support. `Commented` and `No comment` appear recursively in excel file as a pattern. Row #9 in data with these values. Does that make sense?

Comment: So do you mean that every 9th row, your data contains `commented`, `no comment`?

Comment: @Erfan edited question once again for clarity. Hope this helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Define a function to replace the x:

```
import re

def replaceX(col):
    cond = ~((col == "x") | (col == "X"))
    # Check if the name of the column is undefined
    if not re.match(r'Unnamed: \d+', col.name):
        return col.where(cond, 0)
    else:
        # Check what is the value of the first row
        if col.iloc[0] == "Commented":
            return col.where(cond, 1)
        elif col.iloc[0] == "No comment":
            return col.where(cond, 2)
    return col
```

Or if your first row don't contain "Commented" or "No comment" for titled columns you can have a solution without regex:

```
def replaceX(col):
    cond = ~((col == "x") | (col == "X"))
    # Check what is the value of the first row
    if col.iloc[0] == "Commented":
        return col.where(cond, 1)
    elif col.iloc[0] == "No comment":
        return col.where(cond, 2)
    return col.where(cond, 0)
```

2. Apply this function on the DataFrame:

```
# Apply the function on every column (axis not specified so equal 0)
df.apply(lambda col: replaceX(col))
```

Output:

```
  title Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3
0        Commented  No comment
1                             
2     0                      2
3                1
```

> Documentation:
>
> - [Apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html): apply a function on every columns/rows depending on the axis
> - [Where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html): check where a condition is met on a series, if it is not met, replace with value specified.

Comment: Works marvellously! A million thanks. *One more question:* how can I edit the code so that it works for both lower and upper case `Xs`? I tried with an `or` command and also by simply adding another return statement, but neither worked.

Comment: I updated the answer, I also directly created a cond variable to make the code more readable

Comment: Tried the code. Gives me the error: `('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index Specification no.')`

Comment: @mvx: should work now I forgot the sets of parenthesis

Comment: @mvx I also first put `or` instead of `|` now it's fixed and it should definetly work :)

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Thank you very very much for your efforts! :)