# Removing "empty" values from string values in dataframe cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Background:** After finishing [this step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654372/replace-values-in-multiple-untitled-columns-to-0-1-2-depending-on-column), I have a dataframe with columns that have merged values from other columns. The `0s` are all replaced by empty values, as I understand. 
Below is a small snippet of the dataframe. Coulnd't find an elegant solution so also attaching an image for reference.

[image: Dataframe Output]

```
  Summary     Sales     Support     Controls     Design     [...]     Quality                                          
0      1,        ,2          1,           ,2          ,                     ,
1      1,        ,2          1,           ,2         1,                     ,
2      1,        ,2           ,            ,         1,                     ,
```

**Expected output:** My objective is to remove all other "empty" values and all commas - keeping just the relevant number in each.

An alternative could also be to place `0s` in the empty cells.

```
  Summary     Sales     Support     Controls     Design     [...]     Quality                                          
0       1         2           1            2
1       1         2           1            2          1            
2       1         2                                   1
```

Being a python novice, I do not know where or how to begin. I appreciate all help and guidance.

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', ''))`?

Comment: @mvx And after that, remove all spaces, and int() everything

Comment: I think `df.replace(',', '', regex=True)` is more _pandas_ way

Comment: Like this -> ```df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '').str.strip().str.replace('^$', '0').astype(np.int64))```

Comment: @Chris, yes works. Could you explain how it is a more _pandas_ way? I'm learning and I don't know the differences.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski - I get an error, perhaps because of the structure of the data? `ValueError: ("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'API 614'", 'occurred at index Specification no.')`

Comment: @politicalscientist, hah can't believe i didn't think of this. it works.

Comment: Or `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(','))`

Comment: apparently you have some actual strings there too. go with @politicalscientist answer in that case