# Pandas dataframe column headers to labels for data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

**SUMMARY:** The output of my code gives me a dataframe of the following format. The column headers of the dataframe are the labels for the text in the column `Content`. The labels will be used as training data for a multilabel classifier in the next step. This is a snippet of actual data which is much larger.

Since they are columns titles, it is not possible to use them as mapped to the text they are the labels for.

```
Content  A  B  C  D  E
    zxy  1  2     1   
    wvu  1     2  1   
    tsr  1  2        2
    qpo     1  1  1   
    nml        2  2   
    kji  1     1     2
    hgf        1     2
    edc  1  2     1
```

UPDATE: Converting the df to csv shows the empty cells are blank(`''` vs `' '`):
[image]

Where `Content` is the column where the text is, and `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` are the column headers that need to be turned into the labels. Only columns with 1s or 2s are relevant. The column with empty cells are not relevant and thus don't need to be converted as labels.

UPDATE: After some digging, maybe the numbers might not be ints, but strings.

I know that when entering the text + labels into a classifier for processing, the length of both arrays needs to be equal, else it is not accepted as valid input.

Is there a way I can convert the columns titles to labels for the text in `Content` in the DF?

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
>>Content  A  B  C  D  E     Labels
0   zxy    1  2     1        A, B, D  
1   wvu    1     2  1        A, C, D
2   tsr    1  2        2     A, B, E
3   qpo       1  1  1        B, C, D
4   nml          2  2        C, D    
5   kji    1     1     2     A, C, E
6   hgf          1     2     C, E
7   edc    1  2     1        A, B, D
```

Comment: Do you have a link or git repo where I can see the actual data?

Comment: It seems like the empty spots are spaces `' '`.

Comment: Its on jupyter notebooks currently. And I am afraid it is not my data to share on a public forum. Basically I am taking an excel file as input. Converting to csv. then: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654372/replace-values-in-multiple-untitled-columns-to-0-1-2-depending-on-column]. Then, the mapping is in several "sub" columns. I merge the data of these columns. Then try to remove the "string" format by this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818627/removing-empty-values-from-string-values-in-dataframe-cells]. And finally the above step so the data is prepared.

Comment: Same error even after `df.replace()` :/

Comment: I can see from that screenshot, the data is different compared to the toy data.  The assumption has been, only the `Content` column had actual text, while the other columns only had blank or numbers.  This looks like many columns have text, which would explain why nothing has worked.

Comment: @Trenton_M - I didn't realize they would make a difference when I posted. There is only one other column with text. I tried the code after removing the column too, but no luck.

Comment: Yes, for example `s=df.loc[:,'A':]`: `A:` mean all columns from `A` to the right and the first `:` means all rows.  Are the column names, different in the real data?

Comment: Yes, I realized. But the text column I didn't include is placed before 'Content' actually. And as mentioned I tried by removing the column entirely from the df too - in case the code was still considering it. But didn't work. Still checking to see if there is something I have missed in the data that might affect the performance of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199286/discussion-between-trenton-m-and-mvx).

Comment: @Trenton_M Yes, your step by step "note" helped me out at last.

Comment: Well, that took some doing.  Cheer!  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Full Solution:

```py
# first: clear all whitespace before and after a char, fine for all columns
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.strip()

# fill na with 0
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# replace '' with 0
df.replace('', 0, inplace=True)

# convert to int, this must only be done on the specific columns with the numeric data
# this list is the column names as you've presented them, if they are different in the real data,
# replace them
for col in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
    df = df.astype({col: 'int16'})

print(df.info())

# you should end up with something like this.
"""
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8 entries, 0 to 7
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Content    8 non-null object
A          8 non-null int16
B          8 non-null int16
C          8 non-null int16
D          8 non-null int16
E          8 non-null int16
dtypes: int16(5), object(1)
memory usage: 272.0+ bytes
"""
```

We can do [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html), notice here, I treat the blanks as `np.nan`, if that is a real blank in your data, change the last line

```py
# make certain the label names match the appropriate columns 
s=df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]  
# or
s=df.loc[:,'A':]

df['Labels']=(s>0).dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]  # column A:E need to be numeric, not str
# df['Labels']=(~s.isin(['']).dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
```

Comment: 2nd line, you can do `s.columns.astype(str)` as well.

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` for the code. Which probably means that A:E are strings? And I get the error:  TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'` when I use the commented line of code.

Comment: use `df.astype` to convert A:E to int

Comment: I include it in the answer. Alternatively, `df = df.astype({'A': 'int16', 'B': 'int16', 'C': 'int16', 'D': 'int16', 'E': 'int16'})`

Comment: I get the error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[...]'` where `[...]` is the text of the column

Comment: Try `import numpy as np` if you don't have numpy imported, then `df.fillna(np.nan, inplace=True)`, then try using `astype` again.  Also, don't try to convert actual strings (e.g. letters) to `int`.

Comment: Still the same error. When I try the `Content` column's index, the `[...]` is the first row's text. And when I try the index of column `A`, then it is just `' '`. Does that help with understanding the error?

Comment: @Trenton_M: thank's for deleting your answer. I think it would have been a bit unfair creating an answer from another post by only adding some extra infos and just copying the actual logic. This answer looks nice btw WeNYoBen.

Comment: @jottbe I was actually in a conversation with the OP trying to solve his issue because none of the solutions work.

Comment: Ok I see, sorry.

Comment: @WeNYoBen and @Trenton_M I tried again the code with the 2nd line with some alteration in the data. I get the error: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'`. Is there a fix? Would really appreciate the support. This task is time-sensitive for me

Comment: @mvx I don't really know what else to try.  Everything we did works on the toy dataset, but not the real dataset.  At this point, I don't know what else to try without actually seeing the real data, because that's where the real problem is.

Comment: @Trenton_M, thank you very much for patiently explaining this to me and for persistently helping me to solve the issue. I _really_ appreciate it. I completely understand what you mean, and I haven't been able to figure out the loophole yet. As mentioned before though, unfortunately, the data is not mine to share. I would if I could. So I will try to solve it further myself. Once again, a big thank you!

Comment: @mvx Glad to help.  Good Luck.  Reach out if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using `np.where` and `groupby`:

```
r, c = np.where(df>0)

df['Labels'] = pd.Series(df.columns[c], index=df.index[r]).groupby(level=[0, 1]).agg(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
       A  B  C  D  E   Labels
0 zxy  1  2  0  1  0  A, B, D
1 wvu  1  0  2  1  0  A, C, D
2 tsr  1  2  0  0  2  A, B, E
3 qpo  0  1  1  1  0  B, C, D
4 nml  0  0  2  2  0     C, D
5 kji  1  0  1  0  2  A, C, E
6 hgf  0  0  1  0  2     C, E
7 edc  1  2  0  1  0  A, B, D
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int` for the first line of code

Comment: Move the all string columns of the datarame in the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that as follows:

```
# melt the two dimensional representation to
# a more or less onedimensional representation
df_flat= df.melt(id_vars=['Content'])
# filter out all rows which belong to empty cells
# the following is a fail-safe method, that should
# work for all datatypes you might encouter in your
# columns
df_flat= df_flat[~df_flat['value'].isna() & df_flat['value'] != 0]
df_flat= df_flat[~df_flat['value'].astype('str').str.strip().isin(['', 'nan'])]
# join the variables used per original row
df_flat.groupby(['Content']).agg({'variable': lambda ser: ', '.join(ser)})
```

The output looks like this:

```
            variable
idx Content         
0   zxy      A, B, D
1   wvu      A, C, D
2   tsr      A, B, E
3   qpo      B, C, D
4   nml         C, D
5   kji      A, C, E
6   hgf         C, E
7   edc      A, B, D
```

Given the following input data:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

raw="""idx Content  A  B  C  D  E          
0   zxy      1  2     1                    
1   wvu      1     2  1                  
2   tsr      1  2        2               
3   qpo         1  1  1                  
4   nml            2  2                      
5   kji      1     1     2               
6   hgf            1     2               
7   edc      1  2     1           """

df= pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(raw))
df.drop(['idx'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

**Edit:** I just removed `'idx'` right after reading to create a structure like in the original dataframe and added some fail-safe code that works with different datatypes (the two lines below the melt-method). If more is known about how the missing values are actually represented, the code can be simplified.

Comment: I don't have an column named `idx`, it is only the default numbering in the dataframe. I tried removing this command in the code and using it, but the output shows a list of all column headers in the `variable` column as you have written - instead of just the applicable ones

Comment: @mvx, idx is probably the index of the original dataframe, it is in the output you presented. If you don't have it as a column, just remove 'idx' from the `melt` and the `groupby` and it will work the same way.

Comment: Btw. I constructed the dataframe from the data in your question, that is the part "given the following input data". I am sure also the ather preople, who proposed an answer did this, but they didn't add the code to get the testdata for the output they present in their answers. But, if you let it run on your dataframe I am sure it will work, if you dataframe isn't fundamentally different, but in that case maybe it would be better to change the description in your question.

Comment: If it shows all column headers with your code, then the empty cells seem to be converted to empty strings instead of `NaN` in that case you just need to change the line `df_flat= df_flat[~df_flat['value'].isna()]` like above in the edit.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'`.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654372/replace-values-in-multiple-untitled-columns-to-0-1-2-depending-on-column) I converted my data as shown in link. As shown, data was spread over several colums, so I merged it into one per dataset  (Sales, Validation ,etc). The merged data was separated by commas, but had only one number per row. So I removed the unecessary commas. This is what the columns have. //  I tried your code again after removing the str.strip(). Output in new labels columns shows a list of all columns as opposed to just the ones that are applicable (with the mapped data).

Comment: Sorry, I think I can't help you any further. If three people don't get it right here after hours, it might be, that your description is not precise eough.

Comment: Your comments seem to totally contradict what you write in your question.

Comment: I don't think they are. Thank you very much for your time and effort, though. I really really appreciate it!